# Detecting a DragDrop onto a TreeView item

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, drag-and-drop, treeview

I am doing a drag drop from one user control onto a different TreeView. However, how can I detect the drop into the tree view item? I can detect if there is a drop into the TreeView, but thats not the item. I can do an TreeViewItem.Drop event, but thats for when I drop an Item inside the TreeView, not from another control.

I tried seeing the TreeView to be focused, however, that did not solve it. I can detect DragEnter/Leave on the TreeView and it's Items, but not the drop. I have taken a look at other topics that said to have a DragOver to potentially fix this, hwever, but that did not work.

Comment: post some code - even if it doesn't work, it'd help us answer

Comment: What kind of code are you looking for? The event is simply never being called. I have something such as this "<TreeView x:Name="NavigatorTree" ... AllowDrop="True" Drop="TreeViewDrop"" for the TreeView, however, that drop will only be called when you drop outside of the items. For Items, I have "<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle><Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"><EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.Drop" Handler="ItemDrop" />" but that only gets called when an item is dragged onto another item from inside the same treeview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private void treeView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Point DropXY = ((TreeView)sender).PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        TreeNode DestinationNode = ((TreeView)sender).GetNodeAt(DropXY);

        MessageBox.Show(DestinationNode.Text);
    }
```

[EDIT]
Note: You must have the AllowDrop property of the TreeView set to true.
And, you must handle this event:

```
private void treeView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}
```

Comment: This issue is this function (for tree view) will never be called, the event never gets triggered. Despite having the event set up to be. I think this is because I am dragging from a different user control, to this tree view (which is not in the same user control).

Comment: I edited my original answer (I had to add code and the comments do not allow it).

Comment: Unfortunately doing a "e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy" in just the drag over does not allow the Drop event to be called when it should be.

Comment: It works.  You must be doing something wrong.  Why don't you post some code as suggested by others?