# Dragging and Dropping in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, drag-and-drop

I've got a `TreeView` and `Canvas` in my WPF application.  I'm trying to implement functionality whereby users can drag a TreeViewItem and a method should be called when the user drops on the canvas, passing the TreeViewItem header as a parameter to this method.

This is what I've done so far:

```
private void TreeViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Source.GetType().Name.Equals("TreeViewItem"))
     {
         TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)e.Source;

         if (item != null)
         {
              DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
              dataObject.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, item.Header.ToString());
              DragDrop.DoDragDrop(item, dataObject, DragDropEffects.Copy);
         }
     }
 }
```

When I drag and drop to the canvas nothing happens.  I am thus unsure of what I should do next.  I feel that it's something really small, but I'm at a loss.  How can I call the method and detect that the header has been dropped?

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your AllowDrop property set to true?

Comment: Can you post some code showing the markup and code-behind of you Canvas and TreeView? You should have some drag and drop event handlers. Are those being raised?

Comment: Check out the answer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988646/detecting-a-dragdrop-onto-a-treeview-item) You may not be raising the event correctly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set `AllowDrop` to true on your target element and then handle `DragOver` and `Drop` events on the target element.

Example:

```
    private void myElement_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(MyDataType)))
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void myElement_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(MyDataType)))
        {
            // do whatever you want do with the dropped element
            MyDataType droppedThingie = e.Data.GetData(typeof(MyDataType)) as MyDataType;
        }
    }
```

Comment: AllowDrop is infact set to true, so that's not a problem. Could you kindly elaborate on the DragOver and Drop events part? Should those be events of the canvas? How would the canvas' event know that the drop should be transporting the TreeViewItem's header?

Comment: @DotNET: I've edited my answer to add the bones of what the DragOver and Drop event handlers should look like.

Comment: Thanks, that should help me to sort out my problem :)